# Is displaying data by iterating through appended (via DB queries) arrays efficient?

Tags: ios, database, swift, xcode

I am using Heroku as a parse-server host for an iOS app (swift and XCode) I am making. I don't have any issue with my code, but I am wondering if the way I am displaying info (for the sake of being general, they are just user posts) on a table. The way I display the info is by pulling the necessary info from the DB via some queries, and then appending the specific portions of the retrieved data to a few general arrays. The arrays are then iterated through in the tableviewcontroller and displayed that way (think `array[ForIndexPath.row]`). It works fine, but my question is this: Is that a sustainable way to display information? Since the app is in development, all posts are tests and there are only a few. Is this a viable approach if the app were to have hundreds or thousands of user posts? Is there a better way to do this? (My anticipation is that there should be. Having only a few arrays to store specifics info from some posts would cause the arrays to be utterly massive if the user count gets very high, and this would slow down the app. I could be totally wrong though).

Comment: The usual tool for this kind of problem is Core Data and an NSFetchedResultController. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1 Core Data is designed for exactly this kind of problem when the data set may be very large.

Comment: @RobNapier does core data not cause the app to slow down? Because you are persistently storing data on the app? For my situation, it is a relevant analogy to think of the posts I am saving as instagram pictures posted by users. Core Data is good for this kind of amount of material?

Comment: Core Data does not have to persist to disk. But if you're not caching anything between runs, and your thousands of items fit comfortably in memory, then an array of model objects may be fine. Test it. Just because you're in development doesn't mean there can only be a few posts. Generate ten thousand posts and profile what happens. Copy the same post ten thousand times if you have to.